# In linux, how does a parent process apply a pty to a child process?

Tags: c, linux, pty

Here is the code for the parent process:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <pty.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <utmp.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    int err = 0, len = 0;
    int master, aslave;
    char name[BUFSIZ], buffer[BUFSIZ];
    FILE *child;

    err = openpty(&master, &aslave, &name[0], NULL, NULL);
    if (err == -1) {
        perror("openpty faild.");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "pty name: %s\n", name);

    child = popen("./child", "r");
    if (!child) {
        perror("popen faild");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    len = read(master, &buffer[0], BUFSIZ);
    if (len == 0) {
        fprintf(stdout, "Unable to read output from subprocess.");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "child message: %s\n", buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the code for the child process:

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", isatty(fileno(stdout)) ? "true": "false");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I know that in order to pass the isatty check in the child process, it is necessary to interact with the child process through pty, but what needs to be done?

While this may not have an application scenario, I would still like to know the usage of pty.

Comment: `if (err)` won't work, see return value of `openpty`

Comment: You're going to have to write your own version of `popen` that gives the child the slave side of the pty.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you could use `posix_openpt` + `fork` to have interaction between master and slave processes
Following is an example

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <pty.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <utmp.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  int fdMaster = 0;
  int fdSlave = 0;
  int err = 0;
  int pid = 0;


  fdMaster = posix_openpt(O_RDWR);
  if (fdMaster < 0) {
    exit(1);
  }

  err = grantpt(fdMaster);
  if (err != 0) {
    exit(1);
  }

  err = unlockpt(fdMaster);
  if (err != 0) {
    exit(1);
  }

  fdSlave = open(ptsname(fdMaster), O_RDWR);
  if (fdSlave < 0) {
    exit(1);
  }

  pid = fork();

  if (pid < 0) {
    close(fdMaster);
    exit(1);
  } else if (pid == 0) {
    // child
    close(fdMaster);
    // dup stdin, stdout & stderr
    if (dup2(fdSlave, STDIN_FILENO) != STDIN_FILENO) {
      exit(1);
    }
    if (dup2(fdSlave, STDOUT_FILENO) != STDOUT_FILENO) {
      exit(1);
    }
    if (dup2(fdSlave, STDERR_FILENO) != STDERR_FILENO) {
      exit(1);
    }
    if (-1 == execvp("./child", NULL)) {
     exit(1);
    }
  } else {
    // parent
    close(fdSlave);
    int status = 1;
    int len = 0;
    char buffer[BUFSIZ];
    wait(&status);
    len = read(fdMaster, buffer, BUFSIZ);
    if (len <= 0) {
        fprintf(stdout, "Unable to read output from subprocess.");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "child message: %s\n", buffer);
    return 0;
  }
}
```